# BufferStrategy not scaling Graphics2D

Tags: java, awt, scale, paint, graphics2d

I am currently trying to program a simple platform game. I would like to scale the graphics up by a factor of 2/4/whatever so that I can get an old-school look and feel from the game. However, when I call scale on my Graphics2D instance, nothing happens.

```
@Override
public void paint(Graphics g) {

    BufferStrategy bf = this.getBufferStrategy();

    Graphics2D bfg = (Graphics2D) bf.getDrawGraphics();

    mLevel.draw(bfg, this);

    for (GameEntity entity : mGameEntities) {
        entity.draw(bfg, this);
    }

    bfg.scale(2.0, 2.0);

    bf.show();

}
```

The draw calls basically just end up calling g.drawImage(..). Everything else is drawn correctly, so I do not understand why it isn't scaling everything up by a factor of 2.

Comment: Call scale BEFORE you try painting anything

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@MadProgrammer was correct - one must scale the Graphics2D instance before making any draw calls.

```
@Override
public void paint(Graphics g) {

    BufferStrategy bf = this.getBufferStrategy();

    Graphics2D bfg = (Graphics2D) bf.getDrawGraphics();

    bfg.scale(2.0, 2.0);

    mLevel.draw(bfg, this);

    for (GameEntity entity : mGameEntities) {
        entity.step();
        entity.draw(bfg, this);
    }



    bf.show();

}
```